# Error during GCP Storage Bucket access using Rest API from cloud shell

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to access GCP Storage Bucket using Rest API from cloud shell command line. I am running below commands and getting errors. Here the authorization bearer is OAuth2 token.

Please suggest the exact syntax and process to perform GET and POST to GCP Storage Bucket using Rest API.

```
1. curl -X GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/data-dev2-ingest-manual
"error code": 400,
"error message": "Required parameter: project",

2. curl -X GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/data-dev2-ingest-manual?project=data-dev2
"error code": 401,
"error message": "Anonymous caller does not have storage.buckets.list access to the Google Cloud project.",

3. curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer dPO45pZq26wCJWNh66D" https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/data-dev2-ingest-manual?project=data-dev2
"error code": 401,
"error message": "Invalid Credentials",
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Bearer token you're using is incorrect. You may generate an access token for your header within your request like so:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" ...
```

Note that this will generate an access token for the user you're currently logged in with in gloud. You can check the currently logged in user via:

```
gcloud auth list
```

or change it via:

```
gcloud auth login
```

Comment: That last one also may be problematic if the shell you're using treats ? as a special character, for example bash.